# Is there an Rstudio shortcut key for ``?

Tags: r, rstudio, add-in

I use it a lot on Rmarkdow for referring to code, so I created an Addin, but wanted to know if there's a shortcut. If it isn't the case, how could I do to configure the addin so when calling it, the position of the caret or cursor stands between both symbols, exactly as it happens when using `""` or `()` in RStudio.

``` insertInAddin <- function() { rstudioapi::insertText("``") } ``` is the code I used for the Add-in

I'm looking help understanding how to setup

`rstudioapi::setCursorPosition()`
and `document_position()` inside the `location` argument of `insertText`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create macros/shortcuts in R(studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716350/create-macros-shortcuts-in-rstudio)

Comment: What exactly is `"``"`? The chunk thing?

Comment: What's used to referring to code `like this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [shrtcts](https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/shrtcts/) package for this task. It lets you assign Keyboard Shortcuts to arbitrary `R` Code.

1. Create a new `R Markdown` Snippet which can also be used on its own by typing e.g. `in` (for inline code font) and press `Shift+Tab`:

   ```
   snippet in
       `${1}`$0
   ```
2. Use the command `shrtcts::edit_shortcuts()` in the RStudio Console to open the file where you define your custom shortcuts.
3. Paste the following code inside that file (set your preferred keybinding in the `@shortcut` line). Note that the inserted text in the second line of the function must match the new Snippet from Step 1:

   ```
   #' Code Font
   #'
   #' @description
   #'   If Editor has selection, transform current selection to code font.
   #'   If Editor has no selection, write between backticks.
   #' @interactive
   #' @shortcut Cmd+E
   function() {
     if (rstudioapi::selectionGet()$value == "") {
       rstudioapi::insertText("in")
       rstudioapi::executeCommand("insertSnippet") |>
         capture.output() |>
         invisible()
     } else {
         # Gets The Active Document
         ctx <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()

         # Checks that a document is active
         if (!is.null(ctx)) {

         # Extracts selection as a string
         selected_text <- ctx$selection[[1]]$text

         # modify string
         selected_text <- stringr::str_glue("`{selected_text}`")

         # replaces selection with string
         rstudioapi::modifyRange(ctx$selection[[1]]$range, selected_text)
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   This solution uses the native pipe `|>` and thus requires `R 4.1`.
   You can of course just define separate variables in each line or use the     `magrittr` pipe if you use earlier versions of `R`.
   Further the `stringr::str_glue()` command can be easily replaced with a base `R` solution to avoid dependencies.
4. Use the command `shrtcts::add_rstudio_shortcuts(set_keyboard_shortcuts = TRUE)` in the RStudio Console to add the new shortcut with its assigned keybinding. Then restart RStudio.

Now you can use e.g. `cmd+e` without selection to place your cursor within backticks and press `Tab` to continue writing after the second backtick.
Or you can select text and then press `cmd+e` to surround the selected text by backticks.

The solution above can be easily generalized for bold and italic text in RMarkdown documents or to write within Dollar signs to add Inline Latex Math.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [RMarkdown Code Chunks](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-3.html) and [RStudio Shortcuts](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts-in-the-RStudio-IDE).

The shortcut you're looking for is: <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`I`</kbd>.

Or you can create your own Code Snippet. To do this, follow the instructions on this page: [Code Snippets in the RStudio IDE](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets).

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `I` is for calling a code chunk, in my case I want a shortcut for ``, as you used it for referencing Ctr + Alt + I in your answer. I'm looking for info on when generating an Add-In set the position of the cursor in source one unit before the end, in that way it is positioned between the two symbols I called.